# AJAX - can't send multiple data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have following AJAX script.

```
    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/remove_comment.php',
                data: {id: {$commentID}, username: {$username}},
                async: false
                });
```

When I tried to send only one data parameter (id), it worked, but then I added second (username) and it stopped working. I am sure that both variables ($commentID,$username) are set and aren't empty.

remove_comment.php

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['username'])) {
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['id']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username']);
//do something
}
else {
echo 'Something went wrong';
}
    ?>
```

How can I send multiple data through AJAX? When I click the button, nothing happens, not even that error message.

Comment: `{$commentID}` is a wrong syntax

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're using to create the object to be sent in data is incorrect. Try this:

```
data: {
    id: $commentID,
    username: $username
},
```

Comment: Tried it, nothing. Now I checked console and found following:
`data: {
    id: 2,
    username: Juro //my username
},`
And the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Juro isn't defined"

Comment: '{$username}' try this

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it. The problem was, that when server replaced the variable username with my username, he thought that my username is name of (javascript) variable, instead of string. So the solution is replace {$username} with '{$username}'. Thanks for your help anyway.